# Laravel query orderBy nested relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

I have the following relationship:

Unit (HasMany)-> Users -> (BelongsTo) -> Position

I am trying to return an array of units with users, where users are sorted by their position. The property in the position model is 'order' that I would like to use as the sort field. I have attempted the following:

```
return Unit::query()->ordered()->with(['users' => function($query) {
    $query->with(['position' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('order');
    }]);
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not order by nested relationship just using `with()` method. You need to join the relation first. So the code should be:

```
return Unit::query()->ordered()->with([
    'users' => function ($query) {
        $query->join('positions', 'positions.id', '=', 'users.position_id');
        $query->orderBy('positions.order');
    }
])->get();
```

or another way is order using laravel collection [sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sortby)

```
$ordered_units = Unit::query()->ordered()->with(['users' => function($query) {
    $query->with(['position' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('order');
    }]);
}])->get();
return $ordered_units->sortBy('users.position.order');
```